# Get the last added key-value pair from an NSMutable Dictionary

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary that stores a collection of user profiles, how would I go about getting the last added profile?

Comment: Just curious: How do you store a collection of objects (profiles) using a single dictionary.  Do you use the same key for each profile?

Comment: I'm very new to iOS (haven't even made my first app yet) but I was thinking of having an ID e.g. userName as the key and then something like a NSMutableArray as the value. Since NSDictionary is a hash table this should work hopefully. Then I would just use some method to sort through the array.

Comment: fyi: You should do the revere.  Use dictionary as a record of each profile.  And then store each dictionary (profile) into an array.  Each dictionary (profile) record can have multiple key/value pairs:  key:name for value:"somename", key:date for value:somedate, etc...  Later, you can do a search for a dictionary record base on name, date, etc. Also you can use an object class instead of dictionary ... Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again, always good to get another opinion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSDictionary provides no such service out of the box. Feel free to derive another class from it, and store the key of the last added object in an ivar.

Comment: Good call @SevaAlekseyev for some reason it never even crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

`NSDictionary` objects are unordered (and generally in any language, dictionaries are unordered) hash tables. I would recommend using an `NSArray` instead. You could use NSDate timestamps as keys but then you'd have to iterate through every single key to find the most recent one, which could be slow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification however, I need think I need an NSDictionary as it would make searching through profiles easier/quicker? anyways I think I can do what I want using @SevaAlekseyev answer